# const / static / volatile in array type specification?

Tags: c, c11

What does the following function signature define in C?!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void f(int a[const volatile static 2])
{
    (void)a;
}

int main() {
    int b[1];
    f(b);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6qPxaM1vM

I don't get the meaning of `const` / `volatile` / `static` at this place, but it seems to compile, so I guess it has a meaning?

Thanks

Comment: Technically, the code has UB. The `static 2` means that the array passed to `a` should have at least 2 elements, but the array you have passed only has 1 element. (This UB is mitigated somewhat by the fact that the function does not actually access any elements.)

Comment: _Side note:_ `gcc` passes this but `clang` flags it because `int b[1]` is too short. Changing that to `int b[2]` fixes the only warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a mildly useful feature introduced in C99. From C17 6.7.6.3/7:

> A declaration of a parameter as “array of type” shall be adjusted to “qualified pointer to type”, where
> the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation. If the
> keyword `static` also appears within the [ and ] of the array type derivation, then for each call to
> the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element
> of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

Meaning in this case the qualifiers `const` and `volatile` means that the array decays into a pointer of type `int* const volatile a`. Since this qualified type is local to the function, it means very little to the caller, since a passed pointer is assigned by lvalue conversion and can still be a non-qualified pointer type.

The `static` is ever so slightly more useful, as it supposedly enables some compile-time size checks by the compiler, though in practice it seems that the mainstream compilers (currently) only manage to check that the pointer is not null. For example `f(0)` on clang gives:

> warning: null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument [-Wnonnull]

Curiously, `f(0)` on gcc 11.1 and beyond says:

> warning: argument 1 to 'int[static 8]' is null where non-null expected [-Wnonnull]"

No idea what the `8` is coming from, I guess it's a typo/minor compiler bug (the decayed pointer is 8 bytes large).

Comment: the number `8` is a number of bytes occupied by 2 `int`s. But still the warning is quite confusing

Answer (score 3):

A parameter of array type is automatically adjusted to a pointer type.
Therefore a parameter declared as:

```
int A[3]
```

is transformed to:

```
int *A
```

However, with the array notation there is no intuitive place to add qualifier the variable `a` itself (not the data pointed by `a`).
Therefore C standard allows to put those specifier between brackets.

Thus:

```
void f(int a[const volatile restrict 2])
```

is actually:

```
void (int * const volatile restrict a)
```

The size (`2` in above example) is usually ignored. The exception is when `static` keyword is used. It provides a *hint* for a compiler that *at least* elements at addresses `a + 0` to `a + size - 1` are valid.
This hint in theory should improve optimization by simplifying vectorization. However, AFAIK it is ignored by major compilers.

Your code:

```
int b[1];
f(b);
```

is triggering *UB* because only element at address `b + 0` is valid while the hint requires `b+0` and `b+1` to be valid. Better compilers/sanitizers should detect that.

The `static` is also useful for self documentation and detection of errors like telling that at least `n` elements pointed by a pointer must be valid:

```
void fun(int n, int arr[static n])
```

or even telling that the pointer is never *NULL*:

```
void fun(int ptr[static 1]);
```

Moreover syntax `int buf[static n]` is a good visual hint that something is actually *not* an array. It help to avoid a common error when trying to acquire the a size of "array" with `sizeof buf` syntax.

---

**EDIT**

As stated on the comment the word "hint" may be a bit misleading
because it could be interpreted that violation the "hint" is not
an error though it may result in some non-optimality (like performance degradation).
Actually, it is rather a requirement, violating which results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I prefer to distinguish arrays "decaying" to pointers in expressions, versus array parameters being "adjusted" to pointers in function declarators.

Comment: @IanAbbott, fixed

Comment: `static` is more than a hint; it imposes a requirement; C 2018 6.7.6.3 7 says that a call “**shall** provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression” (emphasis added). And Clang does not ignore it; [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/azd44Pr69) shows Clang optimizes based on `static`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I've update the answer. Thanks for pointing CLANG case. I played with vectorization and `static` and I've seen no difference.